# Textarea Resize Handle Image Source

Tags: tinymce, textarea, resize-image

Where can I get the source image for the text area resize image in each browser?

I've got a custom control that is resizable with some standard text areas on the same form (TinyMCE). I'm trying to make the resize handle on my custom control LOOK the same as the text areas surrounding it.  However because every browser uses a different image for the resize handle it looks fine in let's say chrome where it's 2 small bars but it looks goofy in firefox where the resize handles are larger and all dots.

Is there any way to ask the browser for that image specifically so my control will look the same in every browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After way too much research I've found there's no easy way to get the source of the image for the current browser. So I simply made a simple handle image I can use in all browsers that doesn't replicate any current browser handle.